# Unity: How to get y axis in run time generated zigzag path

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am create a runner game like Hilclimb, But i don't know how to generated coin in the surface of zigzag path.
This is my Path 
[image]

it is generated in random. But how to get y position in path in run time, because when coin generated in random position then coin is some time below the and some time above the path.

So please help me how to get path y position in run time so generate coin in the surface.

Path generate code is this, and coin also.

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class TerrainGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    public chunk previousChunk;
    public chunk currentChunk;
    public chunk nextChunk;
    public ManagePower power;
    public GameObject character;
    public Resize resize;
    public Coin coin;
    private PickupResize rise;
    private pickupPower pick;
    private PickupCoin pCoin;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rise=FindObjectOfType<PickupResize>();
        pick=FindObjectOfType<pickupPower>();
        pCoin=FindObjectOfType<PickupCoin>();
        float widthprefabs = previousChunk.WidthGroundPrefab;
        previousChunk.RepositionChunk (new Vector3(-widthprefabs*chunk.CHUNK_SIZE,0,0));
        currentChunk.RepositionChunk (Vector3.zero);
        nextChunk.RepositionChunk (new Vector3(widthprefabs*chunk.CHUNK_SIZE,0,0));
        power.RepositionPower (new Vector3(widthprefabs*chunk.CHUNK_SIZE,-0.1f,0));
        resize.ResizeSquire (new Vector3(25f,-0.1f,0));
        coin.ResetCoin (new Vector3(5f,-0.17f,0));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(playerReachedNextChunk()){
            reassineChunk();
        }
        if (rise.rePick) {
            resize.ResizeSquire(new Vector3 (rise.distancere, -0.1f, 0));
            rise.rePick=false;
        }

        if (pick.poPick) {
            power.RepositionPower (new Vector3 (pick.powerdist, -0.1f, 0));
            pick.poPick=false;
        }

        if (pCoin.distancere < ObjectScript.distance) {
            int random = Random.Range (1, 10);          
            pCoin.distancere += random;
            pCoin.reCoin = true;

        }

        if (pCoin.reCoin) {
            coin.ResetCoin (new Vector3 (pCoin.distancere, -0.1f, 0));
            pCoin.reCoin=false;
        }

        //print ("ddhdhdhdhhd"+ObjectScript.distance);

    }

    private bool playerReachedNextChunk(){
        bool playerReachedNextChunk = false;
        float distance = character.transform.position.x - nextChunk.transform.position.x;
        //print ("Distance  " +distance);
        if (distance > 0) {
            playerReachedNextChunk=true;
        }

        return playerReachedNextChunk;
    }

    private void reassineChunk(){
        chunk refToprivesChunk = previousChunk;
        previousChunk = currentChunk;
        currentChunk = nextChunk;
        nextChunk = refToprivesChunk;

        float xPosition = nextChunk.transform.position.x+3 * nextChunk.WidthGroundPrefab * chunk.CHUNK_SIZE;
        nextChunk.RepositionChunk (new Vector3(xPosition,0,0));     


    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some more information on how you generate and represent your path

Comment: Does your generated path have collider? Do you mind posting a picture of what it looks like?

Comment: Yes I have added a polygonal collider over the path (as shown in the picture above)

Comment: when you have spawned a coin, you could check whether it is below or above the path by performing a raycast up and down

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have access to exact points on your path, but you are using a collider, that approximates the path, then you can use a `Physics.Raycast` or `Physics2D.Raycast` to determine the y-coordinate of the path given x (and if you are in 3D space z).

Given x (assuming you are in 2D space) you could proceed as follows: 
1. Choose a value for y that is guaranteed to be below/above your path 
2. If you select a value for y that is above, then perform a `Physics.Raycast` starting from `(x,y)` in direction `Vector2.down`. You can also utilize layer masks to make sure, you only hit the collider of your path.
3. The y-component of the hit point is the value for y of the path you are looking for